# Why do I keep immediately failing the shooting contest?

Tags: hitman-absolution

Why do I keep getting an "Objective Failed" message with Lily during the shooting contest, sometimes even without having fired a single shot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Precision Aim" button is the same as the "Exit Contest" button.  Don't use Precision Aim.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting design decision.

Comment: *chuckle* oh man, that's gold.